Registros separados en columnas de percepciones y deducciones
He buscado en muchos sitios, incluso en uno de ellos me dieron sugerencias pero no resultaron como lo que necesito.
Bueno explicaré mi situación.
Tengo una tabla MOVTOS, en la cual están los registros de un periodo X, los cuales corresponden a Percepciones y Deducciones como a continuación lo muestro

Necesito crear una consulta SQL para separar las percepciones (2 columnas) y las deducciones (otras 2 columnas) como a continuación lo muestro en la siguiente imagen

Espero darme a entender.
Gracias.
Este debe ser el resultado que deseo

La base de datos está en MS SQLExpress 2014

¿Y qué intentaste?

¿Y para qué querrías hacer algo así? Por favor, dime que es simplemente para una visualización de datos... Sí que se puede, pero indica cuál es tu SGBD, ¿MySQL?

Lo que intente, ya lo deseche, así que de momento nada tengo para mostrarte.

En primer lugar, es muy recomendable que nos pases el dataset con este formato, para que podamos hacer la consulta sin importar los datos desde una imagen:
CREATE TABLE conceptos(
  IdMovto int,
  TipoMovto char(1),
  Concepto varchar(63),
  Importe float
  );
INSERT INTO conceptos (IdMovto, TipoMovto, Concepto, Importe) VALUES
(10, 'P', 'Salario', 1254),
(11, 'P', 'Tiempo extra', 100),
(12, 'D', 'Impuesto', 58),
(13, 'D', 'Seguro', 20),
(15, 'P', 'Gratificacion', 250),
(16, 'P', 'Bono', 50),
(17, 'D', 'Prestamo', 100);

La consulta que buscas es algo así:
SET @i:=0,@j:=0;
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *,@i:=@i+1 id
    FROM conceptos
    WHERE TipoMovto='P'
  ) c1 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *,@j:=@j+1 id
    FROM conceptos
    WHERE TipoMovto='D'
  ) c2 USING(id);

Que daría este resultado:
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| id   | IdMovto | TipoMovto | Concepto      | Importe | IdMovto | TipoMovto | Concepto | Importe |
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
|    1 |      10 | P         | Salario       |    1254 |      12 | D         | Impuesto |      58 |
|    2 |      11 | P         | Tiempo extra  |     100 |      13 | D         | Seguro   |      20 |
|    3 |      15 | P         | Gratificacion |     250 |      17 | D         | Prestamo |     100 |
|    4 |      16 | P         | Bono          |      50 |    NULL | NULL      | NULL     |    NULL |
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+

Pero que no te recomiendo, porque lo que quieres hacer no es más que una vista de unos datos que simplemente tendrías que ordenar y mostrar en la celda que les corresponde.

Muchas gracias por la explicación. La siguiente ocasión que vaya a plantear un problema lo haré como lo sugieres.
Probaré el código en el reporteador.
Reitero mi agradecimiento.

Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. Recuerda validar y votar y Gana +2 de reputación
